# BeautifulSoup not finding xml tag, how do i fix this?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Tried using beautifulsoup to scrape a shopify site, using `findAll('url')` returns an empty list. How do I retrieve the desired content?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soupify
import lxml

webSite = requests.get('https://launch.toytokyo.com/sitemap_pages_1.xml')
pageSource = webSite.text
webSite.close()

pageSource = soupify(pageSource, "xml")
print(pageSource.findAll('url'))
```

The page that I'm trying to scrape: https://launch.toytokyo.com/sitemap_pages_1.xml

**What I'm getting:** an empty list

**What I should be getting:** not an empty list

Thanks everyone for helping, figured out the problem in my code, I was using an older version of findAll instead of find_all

Comment: Try changing “xml”, to “html.parser” and see what that does. I’m not near a computer to try it at the moment, but that’s first thing I’d do to see what’s returning.

Comment: The second thing I’d look at is see if the page loads dynamically. If it is, look at using selenium or html-requests library.

Comment: If you are using lxml for parsing you need to pass "lxml" as argument not "xml" and so you're bs object will use lxml. Let us know if this is enough to make everything work.

Comment: @chitown88 tried using html.parser to no avail, am using requests library to grab the page source

Comment: @lulian previous version of the code, I passed in lxml-xml with no effect

Comment: Only "lxml" not "lxml-xml". One thing man, @Prayson W. Daniel' solution should work fine. You need to use "lxml" insted of "html.parser" when you want to be sure that the document or page is well defined and speed in doing operations (thing that in some cases you don't want so you'll not delay the service of the site)

Comment: If you like I can modify my answer to get values in a list, as @RoadRunner. But if you are familiar with Pandas or or Databases tools as MongoDB, with this you can easily update new rows ;)

Comment: @drip2hard, no `requests-html` library is different than `requests`. requests-html can allow you let the page render before grabbing the source code (if the page is dynamic) [requests-html link](https://html.python-requests.org/), but it looks like you have a few solutions below

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://launch.toytokyo.com/sitemap_pages_1.xml'

soup = bs(requests.get(url).content,'html.parser')


urls = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('loc')]
```

So basically I get the contents and locate loc tag that contains the urls, then I grab the content ;)

Updated: Required url tag and generate a dictionary

```
urls = [i for i in soup.find_all('url')]

s = [[{k.name:k.text} for k in urls[i] if not isinstance(k,str)] for i,_ in enumerate(urls)]
```

Use from pprint import pprint as print to get a beautiful print of s:

```
print(s)
```

Notes: you can use lxml parser as it is faster than html.parser

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `BeautifulSoup`, you can always use [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse your XML urls located at the `loc` tag:

```
from requests import get
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring, ElementTree
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://launch.toytokyo.com/sitemap_pages_1.xml'

req = get(url)
tree = ElementTree(fromstring(req.text))

urls = []
for outer in tree.getroot():
    for inner in outer:
        namespace, tag = inner.tag.split("}")
        if tag == 'loc':
            urls.append(inner.text)

pprint(urls)
```

Which will give the following URLs in a list:

```
['https://launch.toytokyo.com/pages/about',
 'https://launch.toytokyo.com/pages/help',
 'https://launch.toytokyo.com/pages/terms',
 'https://launch.toytokyo.com/pages/visit-us']
```

From this, you can group your info into a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from requests import get
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring, ElementTree
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://launch.toytokyo.com/sitemap_pages_1.xml'

req = get(url)
tree = ElementTree(fromstring(req.text))

data = defaultdict(dict)
for i, outer in enumerate(tree.getroot()):
    for inner in outer:
        namespace, tag = inner.tag.split("}")
        data[i][tag] = inner.text

pprint(data)
```

Which gives the following defaultdict of dictionaries with indices as keys:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
            {0: {'changefreq': 'weekly',
                 'lastmod': '2018-07-26T14:37:12-07:00',
                 'loc': 'https://launch.toytokyo.com/pages/about'},
             1: {'changefreq': 'weekly',
                 'lastmod': '2018-11-26T07:58:43-08:00',
                 'loc': 'https://launch.toytokyo.com/pages/help'},
             2: {'changefreq': 'weekly',
                 'lastmod': '2018-08-02T08:57:58-07:00',
                 'loc': 'https://launch.toytokyo.com/pages/terms'},
             3: {'changefreq': 'weekly',
                 'lastmod': '2018-05-21T15:02:36-07:00',
                 'loc': 'https://launch.toytokyo.com/pages/visit-us'}})
```

If you wish to instead group by categories, then you can use a defaultdict of lists instead:

```
data = defaultdict(list)
for outer in tree.getroot():
    for inner in outer:
        namespace, tag = inner.tag.split("}")
        data[tag].append(inner.text)

pprint(data)
```

Which gives this different structure:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'changefreq': ['weekly', 'weekly', 'weekly', 'weekly'],
             'lastmod': ['2018-07-26T14:37:12-07:00',
                         '2018-11-26T07:58:43-08:00',
                         '2018-08-02T08:57:58-07:00',
                         '2018-05-21T15:02:36-07:00'],
             'loc': ['https://launch.toytokyo.com/pages/about',
                     'https://launch.toytokyo.com/pages/help',
                     'https://launch.toytokyo.com/pages/terms',
                     'https://launch.toytokyo.com/pages/visit-us']})
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way using xpath

```
import requests
from lxml import html
url = 'https://launch.toytokyo.com/sitemap_pages_1.xml'
tree = html.fromstring( requests.get(url).content)
links = [link.text for link in tree.xpath('//url/loc')]
print(links)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to show exactly the way you have already tried. The only thing you  need to rectify is `webSite.text`. You could get valid response if you used `webSite.content` instead.

This is the corrected version of your existing attempt:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webSite = requests.get('https://launch.toytokyo.com/sitemap_pages_1.xml')
pageSource = BeautifulSoup(webSite.content, "xml")
for k in pageSource.find_all('url'):
    link = k.loc.text
    date = k.lastmod.text
    frequency = k.changefreq.text
    print(f'{link}\n{date}\n{frequency}\n')
```